# Sharing a variable between Celery tasks

Tags: python, flask, multiprocessing, celery

I am using Flask with Celery & Celery beat.

I have a task that is running every 2 and 10 minutes. I need to store a global object that each task can access at any given time. Here's my `celeryconfig`:

```py
store = {"foo": 1, "bar": 0}
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    "2-minutes": {
        "task": "server.social.crawler.crawl",
        "schedule": crontab(minute=f"*/2"),
        "kwargs": dict(store=store),
    },
    "10-minutes": {
        "task": "server.social.crawler.crawl",
        "schedule": crontab(minute=f"*/10"),
        "kwargs": dict(store=store),
    }
}
```

I am looking for a way to change `store` from within the `crawl` task, so the next time it runs (after about 8 minutes), `store` is up to date with the changes. Currently, when I change `store` from within the task, it doesn't reflect in the next invocation of the task:

```py
@celery.task()
def crawl(store: Dict[str, int]):
    print(store)  # always prints {"foo": 1, "bar": 0}
    store["foo"] = 2
```

Comment: You could use a cache such as Redis or memcache.

Comment: Just like @Pramod said. Use database, redis or memcache. Each process in celery has his own memory so your code can't work as you expect.